# Kubuntu 16.04 : safely remove ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I am using kubuntu 16.04 on a laptop with the optimus system, and while trying to install/fix my video drivers, I ended up installing ubuntu on my system.

I never launched it, but in the login screen I can select Plasma or Ubuntu,ubuntu softwares got installed (like games), and I'm also getting ubuntu updates.

Is there a way to safely remove the ubuntu-desktop without breaking my kubuntu?

Comment: Are you still looking for the answers?

Comment: Well, my kubuntu is working fine now, no more color/theme problems, but I'm still trying to remove the ubuntu-desktop (if it isn't installed by default in kubuntu), just so I don't have updates for it

Comment: Added an answer.  You can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifying the packages needs removal from a meta-package like `ubuntu-desktop` is hard. But You can get rid of the most of it by removing these packages

```
sudo apt remove compiz compiz-core compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-online-accounts file-roller gedit gedit-common gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-menus gnome-mines gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share gnome-video-effects gparted gtk2-engines-murrine indicator-application indicator-appmenu indicator-bluetooth indicator-datetime indicator-keyboard indicator-messages indicator-power indicator-printers indicator-session indicator-sound libunity-action-qt1 libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-gtk3-parser0 libunity-misc4 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity-settings-daemon1 libunity-webapps0 libunity9 light-themes lightdm metacity metacity-common nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-sendto nautilus-share network-manager-gnome network-manager-pptp-gnome notify-osd notify-osd-icons overlay-scrollbar overlay-scrollbar-gtk2  remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-vnc rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins shotwell shotwell-common thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support totem totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-docs ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-session ubuntu-settings ubuntu-software ubuntu-sounds ubuntu-system-service ubuntu-touch-sounds ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-xenial unity unity-accessibility-profiles unity-asset-pool unity-control-center unity-control-center-faces unity-control-center-signon unity-greeter unity-gtk-module-common unity-gtk2-module unity-gtk3-module unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-photos unity-lens-video unity-schemas unity-scope-calculator unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks unity-scope-colourlovers unity-scope-devhelp unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks  unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-home unity-scope-manpages unity-scope-openclipart unity-scope-texdoc unity-scope-tomboy unity-scope-video-remote unity-scope-virtualbox unity-scope-yelp unity-scope-zotero unity-scopes-master-default unity-scopes-runner unity-services unity-settings-daemon unity-webapps-common unity-webapps-qml unity-webapps-service zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
```

After this command use

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

It will pull packages from `kubuntu-desktop` if anything get removed by previous command.

Comment: ok so what I must do is remove all packages installed by default with the ubuntu-desktop. I'll try this command later (after removing the softwares I'm using). But are you sure all the packages you listed are ubuntu-desktop exclusive? I mean, I sure can run "sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop", but if I don't have to, it'll be better :).

Comment: @Keplyx I made this list from Ubuntu manifest file, these packages aren't in Kubuntu by default. But, if you installed something that pulled anything from it, that too will get removed. For example, if you installed `gedit`, `gedit` will go. You need to install those packages again. I think, since you're trying to be on Pure Kubuntu, you won't need them

Comment: Once again you help me Anwar, thank you so much!! I'll accept your answer once I removed everything without breaking my OS (in a few days)

Comment: @Keplyx Have you tried it?

Comment: I'll try this week end

Comment: Perfect! I just did _sudo apt remove unity_ and _sudo apt autoremove_, and it removed what I wanted! I can no longer access to ubuntu in the login screen, only Plasma. Thank you!

Comment: @Keplyx Great to hear!